# How to film dark screen with bright text in the best possible settings without loosing grey background elements?

Tags: hd-video

Hello dear professionals. I seriously need your help to advice me what settings I need to make to produce a video with dark mode phone that text and white elements would not be too bright and dark would not be too dark.

I have canon EOS 77D. Setting are:25;
frames 1/50 shutter; F6.3 Aperture; ISO 400

[image] This is the best balance I got so far, but I am not amazed by this result at all. What would you say/advice me to improve to get better looks?

I can't get any greys on the screen visible. If i increase the iso or try to increase brightness, the text will be very glarring and way too shining. I try to understand how settings were to shoot a video like in this review video you can see here https://youtu.be/uKk5DTjuJhY?t=520

[image]

Greys are still visible while text is not shining too much.

---

Here is the final video preview

[image]

I decresased brightness on the phone and in the environment. Increased ISO. Then in premiere cleaned grain/noise with neat video plug in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to best take a picture of a screen, like a computer monitor, with a phone camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24871/how-to-best-take-a-picture-of-a-screen-like-a-computer-monitor-with-a-phone-ca)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Photo.SE! While your question is about making a video, the underlying question seems to be about exposing a (glossy) device screen. I've suggested a similar question above. If the answers there don't help, please [edit] your question to indicate what was not working for you, then people can come up with more suitable answers.

Comment: Hi there! thanks a lot. Will try to specify the question!

Comment: What about it isn't up to expectation? The blacks are almost dead zeroes black & the whites are up in the 240s. That's pretty much full gamut.

Comment: Sorry Živilė, I might have not been clear in my previous message, the edited question is not much clearer. Please read the question and answers I linked you to. Does that help you? No? Then please [edit] your question to clarify what is not addressed. Also please include what you mean by "better looks". Perhaps you can include an example image that you want to achieve?

Comment: Ok so actually there is grey background in the background where my finger is pointing and I cant get that to be visible.

Comment: I see a grey background. Is your display correctly calibrated & profiled?

Comment: @ŽivilėAntukaitė that's good information. So the question is actually about getting the photo to show the grey background as well as the deeper black.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think it's difficult to expect that everyone who sees this video has a calibrated screen. I checked this on all my devices (all uncalibrated, laptop, monitor, phones) and the background behind the numbers is only slightly different from the black background. Getting that visible I think is a valid question.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke We don't actually know what it *should* look like. I could see the grey on my [uncalibrated] iPhone, when I posted my comment. It's even clearer on my calibrated computer display, now I'm home. If you try to tweak for a random calibration you will never see… that way madness lies ;) Your only possible hope is to start with it correct.

Comment: @scottbb I'm of the strong opinion this question is only tangentally about video and *is*  "relevant to still photography." The fact that some of us can barely make out the grey box around "B817 35014" on the phone's screen in the still frame grab, while others can't see it enough to understand the question is *prima facia* evidence that it applies to still images.

Comment: @MichaelC Fair enough.

Comment: So here is what I figured out until now. 
If I set lower the brightness on the phone and reduce the light overall in the setting, then the contrast decreases. I also increased ISO and shoot the video. Of course then i got a bit of noise/grain in the photo, but this I fixed with neat video plugin which I purchesed. Actually then I got pretty decent result.
I will add the image to the question description.

Answer (score 0):

In the phone's accessibility settings there should be the ability to set the font size and the choice of high or normal contrast.
Combine those settings with a manual screen brightness setting to get the phone to balance with the background exposure. I.e. set your exposure for the grey BG first.

Comment: Oh thanks! I found it very helpful tip!  Will definitely try this and let see.

Comment: I think when the OP speaks of 'grey background they're talking about the slightly greyer than black box around the text "B817 35014" on the screen, not the background in the room behind the phone?